# ORACLE/SQL: wm_concat & order by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, wm-concat

I'm using oracle 11 (not sure about the exact version, but since LISTAGG doesn't work, I suppose it's not release 2) through ODBC and crystal reports 2008.

Here is the problem I have:

Here's a table:

```
TABLE ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL  
------------------------------------------  
task_card     control_category     code  
------------------------------------------  
1                  zone             17  
1                  zone             33  
1                  zone             21  
2                  zone             18  
2                  zone             05  
3                  zone             55  
3                  zone             32  
3                  zone             72
```

I'm using the WM_CONCAT function to obtain something like this:

```
task_card      zones
1              17,33,21
2              18,05
3              55,32,72
```

Here is the SQL for that:

```
SELECT TASK_CARD, WM_CONCAT(code) as ZONES
FROM ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL
WHERE ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL.CONTROL_CATEGORY = 'ZONE'
GROUP BY TASK_CARD
```

but I'd like the zones to be sorted, so I tried this:

```
SELECT TASK_CARD, WM_CONCAT(code) as ZONES
FROM (SELECT TASK_CARD, CODE, CONTROL_CATEGORY FROM ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL 
ORDER BY CODE)
WHERE ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL.CONTROL_CATEGORY = 'ZONE'
GROUP BY TASK_CARD
```

but for some reason, it returns the following error:

```
Failed to retrieve data from the database.
Details: 42S22:[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00904: 
"ODB"."TASK_CARD_CONTROL"."CONTROL_CATEGORY" : invalid identifier
```

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong here... Can anybody give me a hint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL.CONTROL_CATEGORY from outside the inner query. Try:

```
SELECT TASK_CARD, WM_CONCAT(code) as ZONES
FROM (SELECT TASK_CARD, CODE, CONTROL_CATEGORY FROM ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL 
      WHERE ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL.CONTROL_CATEGORY = 'ZONE'
      ORDER BY CODE)
GROUP BY TASK_CARD
```

Comment: Well I thought about that in the meantime; I tried this : SELECT TASK_CARD, WM_CONCAT(code) as ZONES
FROM (SELECT TASK_CARD, CODE, FROM ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL WHERE ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL.CONTROL_CATEGORY = 'ZONE' ORDER BY CODE)
GROUP BY TASK_CARD - but the omission of CONTROL_CATEGORY in the select gave me an error. Added it back as in your query, and it seems to work fine now ! thanks :)

Comment: @LalitKumarB Why are you asking me?  I was answering a question where WM_CONCAT was (incidentally) used, not advocating its use!

Comment: @LalitKumarB No problem!

Answer (score 6):

For anyone that is still using wm_CONCAT (a.k.a. older db versions):
The solution is to add distinct condition, it will then also apply ascending order to the concatenated values.

Don't ask why it's not documented, but it will work.

Also, using a order by in a subquery, previous to wm_concat will just randomize the order, so it shouldn't have been recommended.

Example for the requested SQL:

```
SELECT TASK_CARD, WM_CONCAT(distinct code) as ZONES
FROM ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL
WHERE ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL.CONTROL_CATEGORY = 'ZONE'
GROUP BY TASK_CARD;
```

Just be warned that the distinct option does not work when used in procedures/packages .

Answer (score 0):

If you give the sub query in the from clause a name you can then refer to columns in the sub query itself

```
SELECT t1.TASK_CARD
, WM_CONCAT(t1.code) as ZONES
FROM 
(SELECT TASK_CARD, CODE, CONTROL_CATEGORY FROM ODB.TASK_CARD_CONTROL ORDER BY CODE) t1
WHERE t1.CONTROL_CATEGORY = 'ZONE'
GROUP BY t1.TASK_CARD
```

Comment: You can already do that even without a subquery alias as the accepted answer shows

Answer (score 0):

1. Order by the desired column, then
2. Order in external query order by row number.
3. Use the function.

This function has logic for the last rownum order:

```
Select wmsys.wm_concat(t) CONCAT from 
(
    Select t from (
        Select t from (
            Select 'aa' t from dual
            union
            Select 'zz' t from dual
            union
            Select 'pp' t from dual
            union
            Select 'll' t from dual
            union
            Select 'mm' t from dual
            union
            Select 'xx' t from dual
            union
            Select 'cc' t from dual
        ) a 
        order by t
    ) order by rownum
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

**LISTAGG** was introduced in **11g Release 2**.

Therefore, in Oracle version **prior to 11g** where `LISTAGG` is not supported, you could use **ROW_NUMBER()** and **SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH** functions.

See **[Oracle String Aggregation Techniques](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/oracle-string-aggregation-techniques/)**

```
SELECT task_card,
  LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(code,','))
  KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS zones
  FROM   (SELECT task_card,
                code,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fruit ORDER BY code) AS curr,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fruit ORDER BY code) -1 AS prev
         FROM   table_name)
  GROUP BY task_card
  CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND task_card= PRIOR task_card
 START WITH curr = 1;
```

**NOTE**

Never use `WM_CONCAT` since it is an undocumented feature and it has been removed from 12c version.

Any application which has had been relying on `wm_concat` function will not work once upgraded to `12c`. Since, it has been removed. See [Why not use WM_CONCAT function in Oracle?](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/why-not-use-wm_concat-function-in-oracle/)

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> SELECT object_name
  2  FROM dba_objects
  3  WHERE owner='WMSYS'
  4  AND object_name LIKE 'WM\_%' ESCAPE '\';

OBJECT_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
WM_REPLICATION_INFO
WM_RDIFF
WM_PERIOD
WM_PERIOD
WM_OVERLAPS
WM_MEETS
WM_LESSTHAN
WM_LDIFF
WM_INTERSECTION
WM_INSTALLATION
WM_GREATERTHAN
WM_EVENTS_INFO
WM_ERROR
WM_ERROR
WM_EQUALS
WM_DDL_UTIL
WM_DDL_UTIL
WM_CONTAINS
WM_COMPRESS_BATCH_SIZES
WM_COMPRESSIBLE_TABLES

20 rows selected.

SQL>
```

You will receive an “**invalid identifier**” error:

```
SQL> SELECT banner FROM v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    12.1.0.1.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production

SQL> SELECT deptno, wm_concat(ename) FROM emp;
SELECT deptno, wm_concat(ename) FROM emp
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier
```

Therefore, there is no point relying on an **undocumented feature** which is no more made available in latest versions.

Answer (score -1):

Use ListAgg instead of wm_concat

```
SELECT TASK_CARD, ListAgg(code) within (order by code asc) as ZONES
```

http://nimishgarg.blogspot.com/2010/07/oracle-differece-between-wmconcat-and.html

Comment: The OP clearly stated that he couldn't use `listagg`. Also, it's `WITHIN GROUP`.