# Oracle SQL put values of a column in one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query were im returning a 3 columns

```
ID    NUMBER    LETTER
123    1        a
124    2        b
123    1        c
123    1        d
```

what I want to do is have a row like

```
ID    NUMBER    LETTER
123    1        a,c,d
```

when I the ID and NUMBER column is the same is one value and t

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970477/oracle-sql-wm-concat-order-by)

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle 11g, you can use the [LISTAGG()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions089.htm) function:

```
select id,
  number,
  listagg(letter, ', ') within group(order by id, number) as letter
from yourtable
group by id, number;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4109/5)